# pandas Series использование replace

Tags: pandas, replace

```
Всем доброго дня!

Есть серия. 

s = pd.Series([111111,"22-22-22","(33)33-33-33",444444])

Пытаюсь заменить символы "-" на "". Не получается заменить. Что делаю:

s.replace('-','',inplace=True)

Out:

0          111111
1        22-22-22
2    (33)33-33-33
3          444444
dtype: object


Что делаю не так?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте например параметр `regex=True`, по умолчанию я так понимаю оно ищет строку целиком под замену, чтобы заменить часть строки нужно добавить этот параметр.

```
s = pd.Series([111111,"22-22-22","(33)33-33-33",444444])
s.replace('-','',inplace=True, regex=True)
s

0        111111
1        222222
2    (33)333333
3        444444
dtype: object
```

Comment: Да, так и есть. Спасибо!

Comment: Для dataframe тоже такой же метод будет?

Comment: @bboris скорее всего да, обычно там одни и те же методы, хотя нужно смотреть, конечно